# Create react app can't use local module with flow types

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app, lerna, monorepo

I created a monorepo which will contain 2 apps created with *create-react-app* and 1 module with shared components. Right now I have 1 *create-react-app* and the shared component module.

For my project I would like to use Flow. Thus I used *flow init* in the root of my project. Running *yarn start* works fine with using flow types inside the *create-react-app* files. But I am importing one file from the shared components with the following content:

```
export class Decision {
    mainTopic: string;

    constructor(mainTopic, options) {
        this.mainTopic = 1;
        this.options = 1;
    }
}
```

For this file I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: /packages/shared_components/model/Decision.js: Unexpected token (2:13)
```

Removing the type annotations lets the app compile. What do I have to change to get the flow types inside the shared components module working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `// @flow` in the very top:

```
// @flow
export class Decision {...}
```

[Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/#toc-prepare-your-code-for-flow)